# style.display = "none" fails

Tags: javascript, html, css

line 5 of my javascript is failing after first click. It 'will' open a subnav and then when I click on a second one, the first will disappear. But that all, after that, every one you click on will remain and will not go away without a screen refresh. .style.display = "none" is completely failing to clear my ma[m] value thus my subnav menu fails to disappear when another value is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/w9ztQ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bite Me</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];
function dropMenu(x){
    for (var m in ma){
        if(ma[m] != x){
            document.getElementById(ma[m]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == 'block'){
        fadeOut(x);
    }else{
        fadeIn(x);
    }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fade_in_from = 0;
var fade_out_from = 10;
function fadeIn(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    target.style.display ="block";
    var newSetting = fade_in_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    //opacity
    fade_in_from++;
    if(fade_in_from == 10){
        target.style.opacity = 1;
        clearTimeout(looTimer);
        fade_in_from = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+element+'\')',50);

}
function fadeOut(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target.style.opacity = 0;
        target.style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeOut(\''+element+'\')',50);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];
function dropMenu(x){
    for (var m in ma){
        if(ma[m] != x){
            document.getElementById(ma[m]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == 'block'){
        fadeOut(x);
    }else{
        fadeIn(x);
    }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body{ margin:0px; }
div#myheader{
height:100px;
background:#D2E9FF;
border-bottom:#09F 1px solid;
}
div#logo{
height:75px;
border:#09F 1px dashed;
font-size:44px;
padding:0px 12px;
}
div#headermenusystem{ margin-left:16px; }
div#headermenusystem > div{ float:left; margin:0px 20px; }
div.dropmenus {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
width:120px;
background:#D2E9FF;
z-index:2;
padding:4px;
border:#0385CB 3px solid;
border-top:none;
-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px;
border-radius:0px 0px 8px 8px;
}
div.dropmenus > a {
display:block;
margin:4px;
padding:7px;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
background:#E8E8E8;
border:#666 1px solid;
-moz-border-radius:3px; 
border-radius:3px; 
color:#000;
}
div.dropmenus > a:hover {
background:#FFF;
border:#06F 1px solid; 
color: #06F;
}
div#dropmenu1{left:24px;}
div#dropmenu2{left:116px;}
div#dropmenu3{left:214px;}
div#restofpage{ padding:36px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- START HEADER -->
<div id="myheader">
  <div id="logo">Test Company</div>
  <!-- START MENU SYSTEM -->
  <div id="headermenusystem">
    <div id="cont1">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="dropMenu('dropmenu1')">Services</a>
      <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenus">
        <a href="services.php?x=pool">Pool Cleaning</a>
        <a href="services.php?x=yard">Yard Work</a>
        <a href="services.php?x=pest">Pest Removal</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont2">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="dropMenu('dropmenu2')">Locations</a>
      <div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenus">
        <a href="locations.php?x=Queens">Queens</a>
        <a href="locations.php?x=Brooklyn">Brooklyn</a>
        <a href="locations.php?x=Bronx">Bronx</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont3">
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="dropMenu('dropmenu3')">Staff</a>
      <div id="dropmenu3" class="dropmenus">
        <a href="staff.php?x=george">George</a>
        <a href="staff.php?x=allen">Allen</a>
        <a href="staff.php?x=frank">Frank</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END MENU SYSTEM -->
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
<div id="restofpage" onmousedown="dropMenu()" style="height:500px;">
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  <p>blah...</p>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly ask you to remove unnecessary code and leave only the required bits (the ones that will still be enough to reproduce the issue). So that we will not have to dig through unrelated stuff.

Comment: I really really really suggest you to use jQuery instead of native javascript language. It is gonna save your time and probably even life

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w9ztQ/1/ I just changed a reference from looTimer to loopTimer and changed when the script was loaded.

Comment: @RyonnSan , jQuery is javascript. Javascript is good to start, then you might need jQuery, Mootools or other...

Comment: To expand on my comment, there was no issue with the `display="none"`, you just had an error elsewhere in your JavaScript. Try reading up on basic JavaScript debugging techniques.

Comment: @Sergio: quite true.
Here is to be exact: jQuery is not native javascript language, but a javascript framework

Comment: @RyonnSan, quite true :) cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found 2 small bugs.

One is `clearTimeout(looTimer);` I think you mean **loopTimer**.

Second is that you define var `ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];` 2 times in your script. Removing that I think it works.

Is **[this (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/MprRa/)** the behavior you expect?

```
var ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];
function dropMenu(x){
    for (var m in ma){
        if(ma[m] != x){
            document.getElementById(ma[m]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == 'block'){
        fadeOut(x);
    }else{
        fadeIn(x);
    }
}

var fade_in_from = 0;
var fade_out_from = 10;
function fadeIn(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    target.style.display ="block";
    var newSetting = fade_in_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    //opacity
    fade_in_from++;
    if(fade_in_from == 10){
        target.style.opacity = 1;
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_in_from = 0;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+element+'\')',50);

}
function fadeOut(element){
    var target = document.getElementById(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target.style.opacity = 0;
        target.style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeOut(\''+element+'\')',50);
}
//var ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3"];
function dropMenu(x){
    for (var m in ma){
        if(ma[m] != x){
            document.getElementById(ma[m]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById(x).style.display == 'block'){
        fadeOut(x);
    }else{
        fadeIn(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the looTimer that got it working, the twin scripts was just a foolish mistake. Works like a champ now!!

Comment: @brad , glad I could help! please click to accept the answer :)